# Compare and swap - What if 2 processors execute locking simultaneous?

Tags: multithreading, linux-kernel, locking, compare-and-swap

I read about CAS in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compare-and-swap, and got some doubts:

- 1. Even though a single lock operation is implemented in a single instruction, but if 2 threads run on 2 different processors, then the 2 instruction could happen at the same time. Isn't that a race condition?
- 2. I saw following sentence in `<Linux Kernel Development> 3rd` page 168.

  > because a process can execute on only one processor at a time

  I doubt that, not sure does it means what it literally says. What if the process has multiple threads, can't they run on multiple processors at a time?

Anyone help to explain these doubts? Thanks.

Comment: The CAS instruction references a memory location, and access to memory is single threaded (i.e. memory is single ported).  Therefore only one core (one process) will successfully execute the "simultaneous" lock operation.

Comment: @sawdust Thanks, can you tell more about `access to memory is single threaded`? Is it a hardware limitation, or limited by kernel? I didn't found more info via googling.

Comment: It is HW limitation. For example on x86 there is LOCK instruction prefix, which can assert bus lock for ensuring exclusive memory access for prefixed instruction. LOCK can be used with cmpxchg instruction for example, implementing simple spinlock on x86

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cpu has a cache for memory, typically 64 bytes of size per so-called cache line. It will do stuff with respect to chunks of that size. In particular, when doing lock cmpxchg or similar things, the hardware thread you execute this on will negotiate exclusive access to the 64-byte portion of memory with other threads. And that's why it works.

In general, you want to read this book: https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/people/paulmck/perfbook/perfbook.html

This particular bit is explained on page 21.

Regarding the LKD quote, there is no context provided. It is safe to assume they meant threads and were updating a thread-local counter.

Comment: By the way, the book looks really interesting.

Comment: If there is something by Paul McKenney on concurrency, you can blindly assume it will be of high quality. Try out his youtube videos, unfortunately there are very few.